# Passing expression as argument: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my actions:

```
>>> def show(d):
        print d
... 
>>> test = {"result": True}
>>> show(test)
{'result': True}
>>> show(test["info"]="Some info")
  File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Why can I not pass expression as argument to a function?

Answer (score 8):

The `=` sign indicates to Python that this is a keyword parameter, not a positional one. Since the part to the left of the `=` is an expression `test["info"]` you get the error.

Comment: That's a good explanation of the error that he is receiving, but not really an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: @Lattyware, that part was already adequately answered by someone else. (Oops, that was you!)

Answer (score 5):

The reason for not allowing assignment in Python expressions is a common, hard-to-find bug in those other languages, caused by this construct:

```
if (x = 0) {
    // error handling
}
else {
    // code that only works for nonzero x
}
```

**Source** : http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want to do is to pass it as a glob type.

```
show(*test)
```

doing this you must match your arg signature so test will have to be defined as

```
test = {'d' : True}
```

or show will have to be

```
def show(result):
```

Answer (score 1):

Because generally it makes no sense. What do you want to get from that? Assignment doesn't return a value.

Let's think of a few possibilities:

- The expression should be passed as a function - you should use lambda, or create an actual function.
- The expression should return a boolean for success - Python raises exceptions on failure, check for those instead.
- The expression should give `None` - there is no value to this.

Either way, what you are trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, it's my missing - I forget that assignment doesn't return a value