# Pandas - df.pipe() - keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have some trouble with pandas...

I'm trying to define the following function:

```
def outlier(frame, col1, col2):
    (frame.pipe(frame.loc[:,"lower"] = frame.groupby(by='col1')['col2'].transform(lower))
     frame.pipe(frame.loc[:,"upper"] = frame.groupby(by='col1')['col2'].transform(upper))
     frame.pipe(frame.loc[:,"outlier"] = (frame['col2'] < frame['lower'])|(frame['col2'] > frame['upper']))
    )
```

Unfortunately I'm getting: 
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Something prevents me from seeing the wood for the trees and from finding my obviously stupid error...

In the following code it works:

This are the functions "upper" and "lower":

```
lower = lambda x: x.quantile(q=.25) - (1.5*(x.quantile(q=.75)-x.quantile(q=.25)))
upper = lambda x: x.quantile(q=.75) + (1.5*(x.quantile(q=.75)-x.quantile(q=.25)))
```

And this is my "spaghetti-code" to add the new columns to a DataFrame:

```
acid81.loc[:,"lower"] = acid81.groupby(by='Ursprung')['Analysenwert'].transform(lower)
acid81.loc[:,"upper"] = acid81.groupby(by='Ursprung')['Analysenwert'].transform(upper)
acid81.loc[:,"outlier"] = (acid81['Analysenwert'] < acid81['lower']) | (acid81['Analysenwert'] > acid81['upper'])
```

Comment: `.transform(lower)` <- don't you need parentheses there?

Comment: Normally not - this lower stands for another function already defined.

Comment: Then you should show us a [MCVE].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide requested information. The error seems to be that you are using an expression as a keyword. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10538717/7443472). How are you calling your outlier function?

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question. And please try to format the code and check if you copy-pasted everything. I just counted the amount of opening brackets and it doesn't match the amount of closing brackets. There is one opening bracket too much in your current example code.

Comment: I tried to fix...

Comment: I think you are using `pipe` wrong. The first argument should be a function, but you are passing an expression. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687205/expressing-pandas-subset-using-pipe) and [the official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html).

Comment: Obviously you are right! I will try to find another way to solve this issue and to make it more general! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you really need to use pipe anyway? Couldn't you just do the `frame.loc[:,"lower"] = ...`stuff and then return frame?

Comment: You're absolutely right! I don't need the pipe, but one hour ago I had this idea that using a pipe could be cool. A "normal" function delivers the result that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, here an answer made from the discussions with the OP in comments:

The problem is that you are using `pipe` wrong. The first argument to `pipe` is supposed to be a function. See [the official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for more information:

> Parameters:
>
> func : function
>
> function to apply to the NDFrame. args, and kwargs are passed into func. Alternatively a (callable, data_keyword) tuple where data_keyword is a string indicating the keyword of callable that expects the NDFrame.
>
> args : positional arguments passed into func.
>
> kwargs : a dictionary of keyword arguments passed into func.

You have to find another way to create your DataFrame.

The easiest solution for this is to just leave it out. You don't need to use `pipe` in this context. Just stick with your example and put that into the `outlier`-function. Then return the resulting DataFrame.